# If an element id is present but still we are getting element not found exception, its reason? how to handle it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit

If an element id is present but still we are getting element not found exception, as its reason? how to handle it.

Comment: Can you please provide a code that is failing and possibly HTML structure of the page where element is suppose to be located?

Comment: Is element just present or visible as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be more than one reason for the element not found reason to be thrown by the system. Most of them are neatly listed out above.

One thing you can try to confirm that element locator is looking for the right element is by searching the element (that failed in execution) in the DOM using the element locator you have used in your test cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities:

- Ajax calls haven't returned values yet
- Initial page was fully rendered
- Javascript still in progress
- Page animation was not finished
- Page rendering of changed content had not finished
- Browser handles queue of transactions incorrectly

The approaches I have used to address them are:

- Ensure all ajax requests have finished
- Ensure the page is fully rendered
- Ensure that all javascript functions have finished
- Ensure rendering is complete
- Explicit (Static) waits (mostly for debugging purposes only)
- Implicit (polling) waits (keep checking for element for max period of time)